# Страница перезагружается при form.submit() даже при использовании preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, ajax

Прошу помощи. Нужно избавиться от перезагрузки страницы при сохранении формы записи голосового сообщения. Пробовал втыкать 'preventDefault()' (возможно, не туда??), но победить пока не удается.
Вот часть кода, относящегося к кнопке Save:

**Update:** проблема решена уходом от form.submit() и переделкой функции save под AJAX. Может кому пригодится работающий код (см ниже). Оказалось, что form.submit() перехватить и preventDefault невозможно. По крайней мере у меня не получилось.

```
function initVoiceMailUI() {
    saveButton = document.getElementById("easy_voice_mail_save");
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", save);
}

function updateUI(btnSave) {
    saveButton.style.display = btnSave;
}

function save() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(recordedChunks[0]);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        var base64data = reader.result;
        var form = document.querySelector("#easy-voice-mail-form");
        form.querySelector("input").value = base64data;
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: И где в этой части кода preventDefault?

Comment: :) я его убрал было, чтобы не смущать своим вариантом. Сейчас вернул)

Comment: Ну ты пытаешься прервать событие загрузки reader, а не событие отправки формы. Нужно отловить событие отправки формы и прерывать его ;)

Comment: saveButton отправляет форму? Поставьте preventDefault()  первой строкой в функции save()

Comment: @Aleksandr к сожалению, этот вариант не работает.

Comment: @Inventor да, идея ясна, спасибо. Реализация хромает: как и куда именно и что иммно писать все равно пока не удалось найти. Варианты ниже пробую - не помогает. Пойду копать глубже

Comment: @Maxim507, удалите обработчик кнопки, он не нужен, слушайте только form, событие submit, на него и поставьте preventDefault,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** проблема решена уходом от form.submit() и переделкой функции save под AJAX. Может кому пригодится работающий код (см ниже). Оказалось, что form.submit() перехватить и preventDefault невозможно. По крайней мере у меня не получилось.

```
function initVoiceMailUI() {
    saveButton = document.getElementById("easy_voice_mail_save");
    saveButton.addEventListener("click", save);
}

function updateUI(btnSave) {
    saveButton.style.display = btnSave;
}

function save() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(recordedChunks[0]);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        var base64data = reader.result;

        // вот это было первоначальным кодом, но его убрали и заменили + добавили function ajax.
        // var form = document.querySelector("#easy-voice-mail-form");
        // form.querySelector("input").value = base64data;
        // form.submit();

        var form = new FormData();
        var url = document.querySelector("#easy-voice-mail-form").action;

        form.append('easy_voice_mail_message', base64data);
        ajax({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: form,
            success: function (response) {
                var button = document.querySelector('easy_voice_mail_save');

                // say to user: data saved.
            }
        })
    }
}

function ajax(options) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var method = options.method || 'GET';
    var url = options.url || window.location.href;
    var success = options.success || null;
    var error = options.error || null;
    var withCredentials = options.withCredentials || false;
    var async = options.async || true;

    // this is a POST data (forms, files, etc)
    var post_data = options.data || null;

    request.open(method, url, async)
    if (success)
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState !== 4) return;

            success(request.responseText, request)
        }

    if (error)
        request.onerror = error;

    return request.send(post_data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как раз `form.submit();` и вызывает перезагрузку страницы (точнее происходит переход на URL, указанный в атрибуте `action` формы). Причем вызов данного метода не перехватывается обработчиками события `submit`. Если нужно отправить форму без перезагрузки страницы нужно пользоваться AJAX

См. также:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: судя по всему, вы правы. Перехватить событие не получается, или (что тоже вероятно:) я не знаю как это сделать, найти окончательное решение так и не удалось пока.

Comment: @Maxim507 Вы хотите загружать файлы на сервер без перезагрузки страницы? Если я правильно понял задачу, решение может быть только одно - AJAX. Перехватить отправку формы после `form.submit();` можно только отключив питание компьютера, выдернув Ethernet кабель (если используется) или выстрелив из дробовика в сторону Wi-Fi роутера/точки доступа (но это еще надо попасть)

Comment: @Maxim507 можно еще браузер закрыть, но это для слабых духом

Comment: Ок, отпишусь по результатам тестирования предложенных вариантов.

Comment: Пришлось переписывать чать под AJAX, что теперь кажется ясным как день) Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте обработчик на форму submit

```js
var saveButton = null;
var form = null; // по аналогии с вами

function initVoiceMailUI() {
 saveButton = document.getElementById("easy_voice_mail_save");
 saveButton.addEventListener("click", save);

 form = document.querySelector("#easy-voice-mail-form");
 form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  // при необходимости вынесите отдельно стрелочную функцию
  // ваш необходимый код тут
 });

}

function updateUI(btnSave) {
 saveButton.style.display = btnSave;
}

function save() {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsDataURL(recordedChunks[0]);
 reader.onloadend = function (m1) { 
    var base64data = reader.result;
    form.querySelector("input").value = base64data;
    form.submit();
 }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отличный вариант, но на практике и он не срабатывает...